# The Edge Coloring

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone tell me how to prove :
The edge chromatic number of a graph must be at least ∆,where ∆ is the largest vertex degree of the graph???

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose (on the contrary) that the edge chromatic number is less than the largest vertex degree, say $d_{max}$. There exists some vertex, say $v$ with degree $d_{max}$ in the graph. Consider all edges of $v$ of $v$. If we colour all $d_{max}$ edges that have $v$ as an end, then we are bound to use at least $d_{max}$ colours, since if we use less than $d_{max}$ colours, at least 2 edges will have the same colour (by [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). Hence edge chromatic number ( fewest number of colors necessary to color each edge of such that no two edges incident on the same vertex have the same color) is at least $d_{max}$

Comment: This is a good answer, but as a matter of style, the proof by contradiction is unnecessary. (You still have a valid proof if you omit the first sentence.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov thanks for the suggestion, I too think now that the first line is avoidable. Btw, what's so interesting about $e^{\sqrt{\log x}}$?

Comment: It's just a weird intermediate function that grows slower than any polynomial that's always surprising when it occurs in asymptotic bounds. (Notably, [Behrend's construction](https://planetmath.org/behrendsconstruction) for 3AP-free sets.)